# iPad: Tabbar item title not displaying

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uitabbarcontroller

Hi Friends i just Added `TabbarController` with `UISplitViewController` and relevant `DetailsViewController` using Bellow Code:-

```
-(IBAction)loginclick:(id)sender
{

    tabBarController =[[UITabBarController alloc]init];
    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];

    NSMutableArray *tabArray = [NSMutableArray array];

    UISplitViewController *HomeSpilitView = [[[UISplitViewController alloc] init]autorelease];

    HomeSpilitViewController *HomeMster = [[HomeSpilitViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomeSpilitViewController" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *masterNavigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:HomeMster] autorelease];

    [array addObject:masterNavigationController];


    HomeDetailsViewController *HomeDetailsViewControllers = [[HomeDetailsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomeDetailsViewController" bundle:nil];

    UINavigationController *detailNavigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:HomeDetailsViewControllers] autorelease];



    [array addObject:detailNavigationController];




    [HomeSpilitView setViewControllers:array];

    [tabArray addObject:HomeSpilitView];

    HomeMster.objHomeDetailsViewcontroller = HomeDetailsViewControllers;
    HomeSpilitView.delegate = HomeDetailsViewControllers;

    array = [NSMutableArray array];




    UISplitViewController *splitViewConntroller2 = [[[UISplitViewController alloc] init]autorelease];

    REMMasterViewController *viewCont3 = [[REMMasterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"REMMasterViewController" bundle:nil];

    UINavigationController *masterNavigationController3 = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewCont3] autorelease];

    [array addObject:masterNavigationController3];


    REMDetailViewController *viewCont4 = [[REMDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"REMDetailViewController" bundle:nil];

    UINavigationController *detailNavigationController2 = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewCont4] autorelease];


    [array addObject:detailNavigationController2];

    viewCont3.detailViewController = viewCont4;

     splitViewConntroller2.delegate = viewCont4;
    [splitViewConntroller2 setViewControllers:array];

    [tabArray addObject:splitViewConntroller2];



    // Add the tab bar controller's current view as a subview of the window
    [tabBarController setViewControllers:tabArray];

    objAppdelegate.window.rootViewController=tabBarController; 


}
```

And i set Navigation title in each `ViewController`  in `- (id)initWithNibName` like:-

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Detail", @"Detail");

        //  self.navigationItem.title=@"details";    I am trying with this line code also
        //  self.tabBarItem.title=@"details";

    }
    return self;
}
```

In Above i am tying also set title with `self.navigationItem.title=@"details` ,  `self.tabBarItem.title=@"details` but still i have same Issue I don't know where is mistake please guide me and help.

Thank you

Comment: which iOS SDK version are you using ? what is the iOS version of your iPad ?

Comment: ios6 and i am working on xcode 4.5.1

Comment: Just try to add titles before adding them to array ie at time of creation set the title in `-(IBAction)loginclick:(id)sender`method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVE**

solve using bellow line just adding before add `tabbarController` in window

> [[self.tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1] setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"BotonMapas", @"comment")];

Answer (score 2):

When you are setting titles to view controllers in initialize methods, view controllers are not in navigation controller stack. Title will be visible only when view controller is in navigation controller. Set titles to view controllers after adding these controllers in navigation controller stack. In your case after creating navigation controllers with view controllers as root view vontrollers.

Comment: thank you for Answer but i solve with other method l[[self.tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1] setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"BotonMapas", @"comment")];

Comment: I had a similar problem to the OP and this fixed it for me.  Thanks!